# play framework v2 deployment on linux

Tags: playframework-2.0

I am trying to deploy a play framework v2.2 application on Linux.  The play framework settings appear to be correct on the server.  However when I try to test the application using "**play run**", I get the error copied below - any thoughts on what might be causing this issue will be appreciated.  Its complaining about a Windows location but I am not sure how to clean that up from the reference.

```
[info] Loading project definition from /home/xxx/abc/play-2.2.1/test/project
[error] com.typesafe.play#sbt-link;2.2.1!sbt-link.jar origin location must be absolute: C:\Users\xyz\play-2.2.1\repository\local\com.typesafe.play\sbt-link\2.2.1\jars\sbt-link.jar
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.typesafe.play#sbt-link;2.2.1!sbt-link.jar origin location must be absolute:
```

Comment: if `Its complaining about a Windows location`, then you might have copied the play folder from a prev play-dist that you used in windows.  Try getting a **fresh copy** i.e. download a new play-zip from the play website and use the new one. I had the same problem just a days ago, getting a new copy kinda solved it.

Comment: this worked.  I simply downloaded play framework directly from the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried following the instructions here:

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ProductionDist

You should never use `play run` in production, it is for development.

Comment: thanks -will try.  As per my question, I am testing and hence used play run.

Comment: play run is also not intended for running on a test server, it's only for development. Use play start.